# Group by one field and also get others fields

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a list of type A with a lot of data and some fields, ex:

```
public class ConteudoAgenda
{
    public string Horario { get; set; }
    public int IdAtividade { get; set; }
    public string NomeAtividade { get; set; }
    public string IdProfessor { get; set; }
    public string Professor { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Modalidade { get; set; }
    public string Kcal { get; set; }
    public string Publico { get; set; }
    public string Duracao { get; set; }
    public string HorarioAula { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to group by Horario and HorarioAula,

I did:

```
var resultGrouped = (from lista in listaHorario
    group lista by new 
    {
        Horario = lista.Horario,
        HorarioAula = lista.HorarioAula
    }
    into itemsGrouped
    select itemsGrouped).ToList();
```

But resultGrouped looks weird and has only Horario and HorarioAula as key...

How can I take the others fields as well?

Comment: What is wrong with that? What do you want to achieve? Have you tried doing foreach on the foreach of `resultGrouped`?

Comment: Also, did you read the documentation of GroupBy? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

Comment: What are you trying to do? Perhaps you are confusing `order by` and `group by`?

Answer (score 0):

`group by` returns a collection of groupings - basically, something like

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<YourKey, IEnumerable<YourFullType>>>
```

Each of the items in the outer collection contains a key plus a collection of rows. It's up to you what you want to do with the rest.

For example, if you wanted to count the number of odd and even numbers in a collection, you could use something like this:

```
var numbers = new [] { 12, 32, 3, 47, 48 };

var results =
  from number in numbers
  group number by (number % 2)
  into groupedNumbers
  select 
    new 
    { 
      Group = groupedNumbers.Key == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd", 
      Count = groupedNumbers.Count() 
    };
```